# Block 1.4 million IP addresses on VPS

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall

How can I block a list of about 1.4 million IP addresses? I've already tried to do it with iptables PREROUTING, like:

`-A PREROUTING -d IP_HERE/32 -j DROP`

But with this many records, my bandwidth goes down like crazy when I do a speedtest.

Without blocked IPs in iptables:

1 Gb/s

With blocked IPs in iptables:

3 Mb/s at peak.

I want to use XDP_DROP like here (last step):
https://blog.cloudflare.com/how-to-drop-10-million-packets/

But I don't have an idea how to use this. :/ (I'm really bad at programing)

Are there alternatives to this approach?

Comment: Can we ask why you want to block 1.4 million IPs? That's a lot of IPs. Might be easier to make sure your server is secure instead.

Comment: There is a new thing named **ipset**. I do not know it, but it might worth a try. It is the new firewall framework in linux, actually iptables today is only a compat layer over ipset.

Comment: If you are trying to block IPs based on location/country, please say so, there are solutions to this that don't involve millions of iptable entries.

Comment: also please don't block IPs based on location/country without a very good reason. Not just "oh there are hackers in that country"

Comment: @peterh, do you mean nftables? I think ipset has existed for a while, and AFAIK it's only about rules that involve, well, a set of addresses

Comment: @peterh ipsets are included in the kernel since [2.6.39](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_2_6_39#IPset), released ten years ago. They already existed before that as an external patch.

Comment: @user253751 Maybe the op is blocking the whole EU for the cookies law? :P

Comment: @TooTea Ok, thanks. What is interesting to me, how the ipset matches an ip to an ipset (which is likely a set of ips with mask). Does it use a tree or hash internally? If yes, it will be very fast. With iptables, the only way to match an ip to a set of rules is linear search because Turing.

Comment: Are the IP addresses really individual IP addresses, or are they part of a limited number of ranges?

Comment: IP's are individual and most are proxies

Comment: Of course it should be a hashed (or it will be otherwise pretty unbalanced) index. "lightning speed" according to the reference in @Cyrbil s answer.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should have a look into [`ipset`](https://ipset.netfilter.org/).

From the official website:

> Ipset may be the proper tool for you [...] to store multiple IP addresses or port numbers and match against the collection by iptables.
>
> [...] (Ipset) may store IP addresses, networks, (TCP/UDP) port numbers, MAC addresses, interface names or combinations of them in a way, which ensures lightning speed when matching an entry against a set.

To use it, you need to create an `ipset`, add the `IPs` and create an `iptables` rule to match with the `ipset`:

```
ipset create blacklist hash:ip hashsize 1400000
ipset add blacklist <IP-ADDRESS>
iptables -I INPUT -m set --match-set blacklist src -j DROP
```

A real life example of usage can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/cyrbil/96389ef47ee5a656d0df1706e1143cfc). Notice that it uses `ipset restore` instead of going through each `IP` in a loop because it’s much more faster.

If your list of `IPs` has overlaps, you may want to preprocess it to convert to `IP ranges` where possible. [Here](https://github.com/rus-cert/compress-cidr) is an example of a tool to do it. It won't get you better performances with `ipset` but it will reduce the size of your list.

---

On a side note, in term of performances, it is very fast and scale without penalty. As the `Cloudflare`'s blog mention, there are faster low level approaches; but it's much more complex and only adds a few bytes per seconds, which, unless you have the scale and ambition of a cloud provider, are not worth the effort.

Comment: Processing single IPs into ranges is definitely a must. Then you can use `hash:net` for the set and even better performance.

Answer (score 21):

Frame challenge - what's the shorter list, authorised or blocked addresses?

Rather than denying 1.4 million, simply allow the perhaps ~dozen IPs you want to permit, and default-deny everything.

Comment: This sound more like he wants to block a predefined set of "Bad IPs". For most applications a whitelist system will probably not be useful

Answer (score 15):

If the IP addresses operate in a well-defined range, then you can use `ufw` like this to block traffic:

```
sudo ufw deny from 192.0.0.0/8 to any
```

The example above blocks all traffic from `192.0.0.1` to `192.255.255.254`, which works out to 16,777,214 addresses and this has zero (noticeable) effect on network throughput.

So long as your IP list is in a workable fashion to generate IP ranges, this may work for you.

Comment: Let us all assume that OP wants to block addresses that are not in a range.

Comment: UFW is, as it describes itself, a frontend for iptables. This makes its performance even worse than manually maintaining iptables chains.

Comment: Why _worse_? It's not like the iptables rules are calling out to ufw, it's just a frontend for configuring them in the first place. Obviously it won't be _better_ either, though.

Comment: @Useless UFW creates more chains for every packet to traverse, whereas manually maintained rules can be *much* simpler and thus more performant.

Comment: So say "ufw generates overly-simple rules and you can hand-craft better ones" or something. UFW's own performance isn't an issue, and the fact that it's a frontend doesn't automatically make its rules bad. It's no worse than hand-written rules that _don't_ make clever use of chains.

Comment: @useless since it is a frontend, every time a request shows up. it is processed by `ufw` which then calls on `iptables` behind the scenes. Once `iptables` has matched ip against the listed rules, It has to pass this info back to `ufw` which would allow or deny. This is the typical fe / be flow. Cutting out `ufw` eliminates half the steps. That said, performance inc / dec would depend not on how many ips are being blocked, but how many requests are actually coming in.

Comment: @NateT I already pointed out that that's absolutely not true. `ufw` just provides a simple frontend for `iptables`, which itself just configures rules in the `ip_tables` netfilter module. Packet filtering activity never flows from the `ip_tables` kernel module out to the `iptables` userspace component, much less the `ufw` frontend for that.

Comment: Then it is NOT A FRONTEND. App 1 updating the app 2 data store does not make app 1 a "front end" for app 2. If both apps are not being called on in the order I described, you can call it whatever else you want (call it "Nancy in her red dress" for all I care), but calling it a front end in a discussion about speed-of-algorithm is never a good idea. Users of this network are always catching flak for being too picky about terms, but ^this^ is what a slightly misused term can do. @useless

Comment: If I am misunderstanding, please describe the flow of events. If both apps are being used, they are both taking up memory and temporal resources, even if they are only printing hello world to the console. You know what? Ill look it up so you dont have to type it. I'm curious now anyway. The only exception I can think of is the case where iptables is not called at all and only its data is used / updated. In that case, ^^^

Answer (score 13):

You can minimize look-ups to gain more speed by **tree-structuring** your rules. You can for example do it based on the first part of the IP i.e. `/8` like so:

```
iptables -N rule8_192_0_0_0
iptables -N rule8_172_0_0_0
iptables -N rule8_10_0_0_0

iptables -A INPUT -s 192.0.0.0/8 -j rule8_192_0_0_0
iptables -A INPUT -s 172.0.0.0/8 -j rule8_172_0_0_0
iptables -A INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/8 -j rule8_10_0_0_0

iptables -A rule8_192_0_0_0 -s 192.168.2.3 -j DROP
iptables -A rule8_172_0_0_0 -s 172.16.2.3 -j DROP
iptables -A rule8_10_0_0_0 -s 10.10.2.3 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 5):

There's another improvement that directly solves your 3 Mb/s problem:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

This allows established connections to traverse as few iptables rules as possible, although using ipset to improve the IP address lookup speed is still necessary for *new connections* to establish faster.

No matter how many other rules you have, this is a good one to deploy as the first rule.

Answer (score 2):

XDP_DROP is probably overkill unless you plan on running these blocklists at extremely high packet speeds (Think >1mpps). As such i would recommend Cyrbil's anwser if you aren't that experienced with code.

If you nevertheless want to try with XDP you are looking for something called a [bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) which is able to quickly check if a ip is "possibly in set" or "definitely not in set"

A example of a bloom filter in C: [This blog post](https://drewdevault.com/2016/04/12/How-to-write-a-better-bloom-filter-in-C.html)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't use iptables but the ip kernel routing table, it may be worth trying it and check for performances:

`ip route add blackhole IPv4/32`

IIRC it's supposed to be faster than filtering with iptables, but I've never done a benchmark with 1.4 million IPs :)